# Register ActiveX SERVER in Linux through wine

Tags: wine, activex-exe

I have a windows application written in VB6 that uses an ActiveX exe.
On program startup i am registering ActiveX exe with /regserver option.

We wanted to test this application in linux through wine.

Installer worked fine and when program is launched through wine i got 
'Object doesn't support action' message.

So i thought it might be ActiveX EXE Registration,so tried to register manually through 'wine cmd' option.There also i am getting same message.

Is this option (/Regserver) not suppported through Wine?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
wine regsvr32 file.dll or file.ocx
```

i hope this helps you